# Microsoft recommends using Rowversion over timestamp, but I can not find "rowversion" data type inside my sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) mentioned that we should use the rowversion data type over Timestamps. Now inside my SQL Server 2008 R2, I want to create a column with the Rowversion data type. But in my SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio, I cannot find such a data type:

[image]

Also when I tried altering existing column named timestamp which is of type timestamp using this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE [SkillManagement].[dbo].[Customer]
ALTER COLUMN timestamp rowversion
```

I get this error:

```
Msg 4927, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot alter column 'timestamp' to be data type timestamp
```

Can anyone advise?

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: well, timestamp is a synonym of the rwoversion datatype, so...

Comment: what do u mean exactly ?

Comment: I mean that timestamp is a synonym of rowversion, it's the exact same data type with another name

Comment: so i can not change the column type from timestamp to rowversion ?

Comment: but on this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx they mentioned that we need to use rowversion instead of timestamp whenever possible,,, so should i drop exsisitng column and create new column of type row version  ?

Comment: You should **AVOID** using reserved keywords (like `TIMESTAMP`) as column names - use something more meaningful! Then it'll work.

Comment: but timestamp is meaningful

Comment: ok i re-named the column to be RV . i tried this ALTER TABLE [SkillManagement].[dbo].[Level]
ALTER COLUMN RV rowversion. but i got the same error ???

Comment: @johnG `timestamp` is not meaningful in that context. Unless you think that `rowversion` contains information about date and time, it's actually quite misleading.

Comment: i want to use timestamps or row version to handle concurrency exceptions inside my application, i will not query or display this info..

Comment: @johnG that doesn't change the fact that *you should not use reserved words for column names*.

Answer (score 23):

`rowversion` is just an alias for `timestamp`. Under the covers, they are the exact same thing.

If you're using the GUI (prior to 2012), you have to use `timestamp`. (Peripheral hint: please stop using the GUI.)

But it doesn't stop there. Even if you generate this table using DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.x(y ROWVERSION);
```

The data type in the metadata will be `timestamp`:

```
SELECT t.name 
  FROM sys.types AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
  INNER JOIN sys.tables AS st
    ON c.[object_id] = st.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON st.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE st.name = N'x'
    AND s.name = N'dbo'
    AND c.name = N'y';
```

And if you generate a script for this table, it will also include `timestamp`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[x](
    [y] [timestamp] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And in fact:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE name = N'rowversion';
```

Results:

```
----
0 row(s) affected.
```

So there isn't even a type in the system named `rowversion` - any DDL that includes it gets parsed and translated *before* the DDL is even executed against the server.

Microsoft has been a walking contradiction on this since they first introduced the poorly-named data type (which also happens to violate the SQL standard, which dictates that the `timestamp` data type should be used for date/time data). I asked back in 2007 for this to be properly deprecated. [My Connect item is still active](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/274333/) *([archive](http://archive.is/Tv0ab))*- feel free to vote and, more importantly, comment about how the documentation contradicts the possible usage of the product.

[Others have written about this too](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/if-timestamp-is-deprecated-why-do-none-of-the-current-db-tools-support-rowversion/).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64587/discussion-on-answer-by-aaron-bertrand-microsoft-recommends-using-rowversion-ove).

Comment: Connect has been moved to UserVoice, you might want to update the link...

Comment: @jmoreno Oh, that sounds like an easy task. There are 114 posts on here with links to Connect, and there is no direct translation to UserVoice URLs, so every single one is a manual expedition trying to discover if that item even made it over (because not everything did). I have some real work to do first. :-)

Comment: Microsoft sort of took your idea of deprecating in Microsoft Connect. Unfortunately they got it backwards, and deprecated Microsoft Connect!  *don't have to fix bugs if we delete all bug reports*

Comment: This one seems to be at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32889865-deprecate-timestamp-the-keyword-not-rowversion-i

Answer (score 2):

Timestamp is a synonym for the rowversion datatype.

You can find it in this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) article.

Microsoft has marked timestamp as deprecated as you can see in the article mention above, but still in SQL Server 2012 Mgmt Studio uses timestamp even if you create the table with the rowversion datatype.

Comment: Yes i already read this article and that why i want to modify the data-type for all my timestamps columns to start using rowversion... so how i can do so ? should i drop exsisting timestamp columns and create new rowversion?

Comment: No, right now (even in SQL 2012) you can't use the keyword rowversion, you should still use the synonym timestamp. Even if you create a table in SQL 2012 with a rowversion SSMS generates you a create script with the "datatype" timetsamp.

Comment: so this seems confusing a bit ? MSDN link mentioned that we should consider using rowversion instead of timestamp,, but there is no datatype for rowversion even on sql server 2012 ??/

Comment: Yeah, it's really confusing. I think the main goal is that you should not use timestamp as name for the column. With timestamp you didn't have to specify a column name, it was automatically set to timestamp, with rowversion you would have to specify a column name.

Comment: not sure i understand your point,, they are talking about using rowversion instead of timestamp as the data type not the column name...

Comment: also i install sql server 2012 express and it allow to directly specifying data type as "rowversion" !!!

Comment: What's your SQL server Version? We have 11.0.2100 and no rowversion. Here is an article on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/625109/rowversion-type-not-found-in-table-design) regarding this Problem.

Comment: no i have 10.50.4000.0 for the client tools and managment studio...

Comment: now i installed sql server 2012 express inside visual studio 2013. and seems it will provide a data type named rowversion, also the generate script will include "rowversion" not timestamp. so seems this issue is related with sql server 2008 and not 2012 ? and still sql server 2012 provides data type named timestamp ... can you check my edit ,,with a screen shot for sql server 2012? thanks

Comment: Management studio 2014 still uses timestamp and not rowversion as the data type name.  Why? it is so stupid.