# SQL Server - Timestamp datatype

Tags: sql-server

I need some information on SQL Server timestamp.

I found all the required information [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.110).aspx).

The article says

> The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Sample syntax is  to create timestamp column is

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable (PriKey int PRIMARY KEY, timestamp);
```

The new syntax is

```
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable2 (PriKey int PRIMARY KEY, VerCol rowversion) ;
```

So the question is, the word deprecated means Is Microsoft going to completely remove the timestamp datatype or it is removing just the syntax of using it ?

As I am using SQL Server 2014, in Design mode, I am still able to see timestamp datatype.

So can someone please clarify my doubt ?

And also is there any alternative datatype for timestamp, I want to use it for concurrency check ?

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86523/microsoft-recommends-using-rowversion-over-timestamp-but-i-can-not-find-rowve

Comment: I don't really get the question in your last sentence. "is there any alternative datatype for timestamp" – you've said it yourself that the new syntax is *rowversion*. That's the alternative you should use.

Comment: Note that while Microsoft has been saying for multiple versions that `timestamp` keyword (NOT the functionality!) is deprecated, even in SQL Server 2016 if you create a table using `rowversion`, the metadata still stores `timestamp` and that's what you'll get if you, for example, script out the table.

Comment: @andriy my last question was alternative data type for time stamp, not syntax. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the timestamp syntax is deprecated, not the whole datatype. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx), just use the rowversion syntax going forward.

For concurrency checks, rowversion is what you're looking for. The timestamp synonym still works, but is just an alternate name for rowversion. There are no other datatypes that behave similarly.

Comment: Thanks all. Actually in gui, I didn't find rowversion , that's where i confused.

Comment: @JSantosh Yeah, the table designer is terrible. Just don't use it.